# File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it on feature mofule

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-chipmunk

I'm trying to execute a composable preview in a device that is under a feature module and I got this error: [image]

It is asking for **google-services.json** file even when this is present in the main **app** module. Maybe some of you know how to fix this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compose Preview creates a separate app, not sure if it's possible to copy file there. any firebase related code should perfectly be in your view model, and not used directly in the composables during preview.